# Using realloc in dynamic structure array

Tags: c, struct, malloc, structure, realloc

I am trying to use realloc to dynamically create instances of a struct, filling it with data from a temporary structure as I go. The program crashes when it reaches the line to malloc a pointer of the structure a second time but I am not sure how I should structure this function. I have the following code:

```
#define MAX_STRING 50

struct data {
int ref; 
int port;
char data[MAX_STRING+1];
}valid, invalid;

void read_file(FILE *file);
void validate(struct data* temp); 

int g = 0;

int main(){

    char inputfile[100];
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt" , "r");

    if (file != NULL){
       read_file (file);
    }

    else{
    // Some code here..
    }

    return 0;
}  

void read_file(FILE *file){

    struct data* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct data));

    char buf[1024];
    while(!feof(file)){

       fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file))

       sscanf(buffer, "%d.%d.%s", &temp->ref, &temp->port,  &temp->data);

       validate(temp);
       g++;

    }
}

void validate(struct data* temp){

    if((some condition) && (some condition))
    {
        create_valid(temp);
    }

    if((some condition) && (some condition))
    {
        create_invalid(temp);
    }
}
```

I am unsure of how to structure the following function:

```
int create_vaild(struct data* temp){

    struct data* valid = malloc(sizeof(struct data)); <<<<<<<<< Line that crashes 

    valid = realloc(valid, g * sizeof(struct data));

    valid[g] = *temp;

    if (valid[g] == NULL){
        //error.
    };
    printf("\n%i:%i:%s\n", (valid+g)->ref, (valid+g)->port, (valid+g)->data);



return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the line that is causing crash?

Comment: Show a minimal example please, who knows what is happening with `g`.

Comment: See also related previous question [Variable sized object may not be initialized creating structure array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478195/variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized-creating-structure-array).

Comment: Note: 1) Rather than `while(!feof(file)){ fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file))`, use `while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) != NULL)`.  2) Check the results of `sscanf()` --> `if(3 != sscanf(buffer, "%d.%d.%50s",&temp->ref, &temp->port,  temp->data)) break;`  (Notice 50 and `temp->data` without `&`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see one potential problem:

You have g set to 0 i.e.

```
int g =0;
```

You are not incrementing it before the call to `create_valid()`. You are using this value to allocate memory inside that functions:

```
valid = realloc(valid, g * sizeof(struct data));
```

So now `g` is `0`.

Later in the next line you dereference this pointer

```
valid[g] =  *temp;
```

This is some memory which you have not allocated as `realloc()` didn't allocate memory for you becasue you passed 0 to it.Hence the crash.

Comment: This may be because the whole code is not posted. The part that fails has one certain typo in `int create_vaild()` so it's anybody's guess (as usual) whether anything wrong is real or fictitious.

Comment: anyway no matter what value `g` has, allocating `g * sizeof(struct data)` and then accessing `valid[g]` is always wrong